# Linux, two mouses, two layouts at the same time

Tags: linux, mouse, keyboard-layout

I want two connected USB mouses in Linux (Ubuntu 17.10 now):

- one with left-handed buttons layout
- one with right-handed buttons layout

^ at the same time.

I'm switching hands on my mouse frequently, switching also layout every time. I do so because I have two displays, a keyboard on my lap and I rotate to the currently used display. The main button ("left") is always towards the center, so I use left-handed layout for the left hand, and right handed for the right hand. I have two mouses, I'd like to have them on both sides always ready to use with the respective layouts. How can I achieve that?

I don't want to use the same layout for both sides because in my brain I strongly connected the main button to the center. Switching manually like now will take less time+effort than learning the "normal" layout with my left hand. More importantly, this is the right tactic if you want ambidexterity, because you can mirror your skills, transferring them quick instead of re-learning (quicker than first learning, but still slow).

Thanks! :)

Comment: Wayland? X? libinput or evdev? What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: @dirkt `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` → `unity`. How to check for libinput vs evdev? I've got files for both.